# Trouble setting up DNS for VPS

Tags: dns, vps, no-www, namecheap

I had registered a domain at namecheap and forwarded the DNS to my host at `vps.net`.

The strange thing is, when I did that the site was showing up. I even uploaded files and everything was displaying correctly on my new domain.

Now, it is just the namecheap holding page again. I have no idea why this is happening as I haven't touched the configuration since it was working.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

When I enter `http://example.com` it redirects to `http://www.example.com` and the namecheap holding page is shown. Prior to this `domain.com` was showing what the host was serving.

I am completely lost and have no idea where to start so I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: How long ago did you make the DNS changes? Have you given them long enough to propagate?

Comment: Name your domain! We aren't shamans here

Comment: Remember to use [a proper example domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) as per RFC 2606 when giving examples. Or, give your actual domain as Lazy Badger suggests (probably a better option in this particular case).

Comment: Unless you provide a domain, your answers will end up very subjective

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am not familiar with any of those service providers I would suggest to:

1. Check you DNS A records and make sure (even if you already are sure) that they point to the IP of the vps/machine you wanna make use of.
2. If those are set up correctly, check your vps's server's configuration settings for the default host and any possible redirects for `yourdomain.com`.
3. If the above are set correctly, contact the registrar and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar thing just happened to me. I'm guessing there was a delay in the DNS changes I made. Give it 24hr if you can wait and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the change had worked before, I would contact your registrar to find out why it reverted back. I, for example, use 123-reg to buy my domains and administrate them, but the domain names use `6sync.net` for the DNS. I did have an issue with a domain name and it turned out a DNS record was wrong on the domain name which they then changed for me (I never asked them to, which was quite nice).

While you register your domain name through a registrar they do have access to change your DNS (and other records) without you knowing.

It would be handy to know how long it was working for too, if it was longer than 24 hours then I would contact your registrar. Otherwise I'd wait to see if it propagates. Then call them.